# How to Multi Upload Images and Save it to Database Codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I want to multi-upload an images using codeigniter and save it into a table, seems no error shown on my code, but returned no results (a.k.a Not Saved to Database and Images not uploaded)

Here's my code on Controller

```
public function tambah_proses()
{
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $dataInfo = array();
    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];
 
        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
        $this->upload->do_upload('userfile[]');
        $dataInfo[] = $this->upload->data();
    }
 
    $data = array(
        'pic_id' => $this->input->post('pic_id'),
        'img1' => $dataInfo[0]['file_name'],
        'img2' => $dataInfo[1]['file_name'],
        'img3' => $dataInfo[2]['file_name'],
        'img4' => $dataInfo[3]['file_name']
     );
 
     $this->Product_model->insert($data);
}

private function set_upload_options()
{
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path']      = 'upload/images';
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    $config['max_size']         = '2048'; // 2 MB
 
    return $config;
}
```

on View :

```
<form action="<?php base_url("admin/products/tambah_proses") ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<input type="hidden" name="pic_id" value="<?php echo $product->product_id?>" />
                        
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Gambar Tambahan*</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="userfile[]" multiple> <br/><br/>
    </div>
                        
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="btn" value="Save" />
</form>
```

On Model :

```
function insert($data)
    {
      $this->db->insert('prod_pict', $data);
    }
```

Can you tell me what's wrong on my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the following issues:
First, include "echo" before the base_url(in form action) like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url("admin/products/tambah_proses") ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Then correct your controller code as follows:

```
public function tambah_proses()
{
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $dataInfo = array();
    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {
       if($i < 4){
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];
 
        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
        $this->upload->do_upload('userfile[]');
        $dataInfo[] = $this->upload->data();
     }
    }

    $data = array();
    $counter = 1;
    foreach($dataInfo as $one){
        if ($counter <= 4) {
            $index = "img".$counter;
            $data[$index] = $one['file_name'];
        }       

    }

    $data['pic_id'] = $this->input->post('pic_id');
 
    $this->Product_model->insert($data);
}
```

Basically your old code would throw an error when the user uploads less than 4 files by accessing it via an absolute index like:

```
$dataInfo[3]['file_name']
```

Inorder to prevent this, I looped through the datainfo array such that it executes based on the number of array items held. And since you have atmost 4 images required, the code executes as long as the counter is less or equal to 4.